# Use 2nd GPU w/ 2nd monitor for fullscreen simultaneously w/1st?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've got a GTX 970 hooked up to a 144hz G-sync monitor, and that's my main display.

I've also got a GT 710 hooked up to a cheap little 1600x900 monitor, and that's my secondary display.

The rationale behind the second GPU was that I didn't want my primary to have to draw the extra pixels. I'm not sure if that's even how it works, but hey, the second card was cheap.

Is there any way to run a fullscreen application on each of them simultaneously? (I'm trying to build a full system stress test for watercooling and power capacity tests.)